# WARNINGS: ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/var/www/static/' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist

Tags: django

Estoy aprendiendo django y me aparece el error WARNINGS: ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/var/www/static/' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist. y no me deja realizar cambios en mis archivos estaticos y no se como solucionarlo

intente probando con import os y cambiando STATICFILES_DIRS por STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")] pero aun nada